# No sound after update Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound

I just did a un-harmful:

```
sudo apt-get update; apt-get upgrade --yes
```

I rebooted, and now no output sound. The driver is there, apparently, working, since it detect both mic from headphones and digital webcam, and moves "bar sound" when I touch them.

Any hints to where I start? I just don't want to downgrade it... just considering it as my last option, 'cause I'll have to do a lot of other stuff. =/

I checked alsamixer, and everything seems okay there too...

Comment: Me too. Please Help!